# What is the Transformation Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Solved.

I'm studying my midterm exam and solving the problem set. Unfortunately, there is no solution manual for this set. I will show what I did and I will ask my specific question. Firstly, the question is the following:

Let $V$ be the space of polynomials with real coefficients of order less than or equal to $2$,
with elements in the form $p(t) = at^2 + bt + c$. Let $W$, $\Bbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$, i.e., the space of $3 \times 2$
matrices with real elements. Consider the linear transformation $T : V \to W$ defined
below.

$$T(p(\cdot)) = \begin{bmatrix}p(0)&p(1)\\p(1)&p(0)\\p(0)&p(1)\end{bmatrix}.$$

I want to find the transformation matrix, the null space, and the range space of $T$.

I found that:

- Basis of $V=\{1,t,t^2\}$
- Basis of $W=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

By using these bases I found the transformation matrix as follows:

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&0&0\\1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

By using this transformation matrix, I thought that the null space is $\operatorname{span}\{t^2 - t\}$.

However, I could not found the range space. What should I do to find range space? And I am not sure that I found the transformation matrix correctly. Is it correct, or did I do something wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: The Range Space is the following:

$R(T)=span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 1&0 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix} \right\}$

Comment: More MathJax please.

Comment: Your matrix and null space are correct. The range space is the subspace of $\Bbb R_{3\times2}$ spanned by $T(1),T(t),T(t^2).$ Note that $T(t^2)=T(t).$

Comment: @AnneBauval

Thanks for your help ^^. What do you mean with the notation of T(1),T(t),T(t^2).
I could not understand what is the form of the elements of range space.

Comment: @KurtG.

I guess MathJax is about the form of writing my question. Do you have any link so that I can learn the shortcuts.

Comment: @PoorMScStudent Regarding MathJax, you could start [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site), and move on to [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you want to see how I've formatted your question, click the [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4603800/edit) button. You can play around with the code and see how things change, so long as you don't submit your changes.

Comment: @TheoBendit
Thank you. I will learn the notation exactly after my midterm exam ^^

Comment: @PoorMScStudent Your range is not correct. The range should be a subspace of the codomain, i.e. $\Bbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$, and neither of the vectors in your spanning set are $3 \times 2$ matrices. Try following Anne's comment again. What is $T(1)$? What is $T(t)$ and $T(t^2)$?

Comment: @TheoBendit
I edited many times, sorry. I am still learning the typing.

$R(T)=span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\ 1& 1\\ 1& 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0& t \\ t& 0 \\ 0& t\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

Since $T(t)$ and $T(t^2)$ are equal, I think I don't need $T(t^2)$ in the range space. Am I right?

Comment: Definitely closer. There shouldn't be a $t$ in your basis though. Note that $T(t) = T(t^2) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141477/discussion-between-poor-msc-student-and-theo-bendit).